# Vite: unable to build enum (typescript) when using absolute import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, frontend, vite

When trying to absolute import an Enum, it seems that Vite is unable to build it.
Typescript correctly resolve the absolut import. Vite is trying to do the same via  `vite-tsconfig-paths`

Typescript and Vite config files:

```
// tsconfig.json

{...}
"paths": {
      "@*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "@types/*": [
        "src/enums/*",
      ],
{...}
```

```
// vite.config.ts

/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './test/setup.js',
  },
})
```

Enum is something like this:

```
// src/enums/common/fooEnum.ts

export enum foo = {
 BAR = 'bar',
 BAZ = 'baz'
}
```

`Common` folder also contains an `index.ts` that just re-exports the enum:

```
// src/enums/common/index.ts

export {foo} from './fooEnum'
```

Then importing in a file like so:

```
// reactComponent.tsx

import {foo} from '@types/common'
```

Typescript imports it correctly, IDE doesn`t throw any errors, but Vite in the previsualization of the app shows the next error:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "@enums/common" from "src/path/to/file.tsx". Does the file exist?

20 |  
21 |  import { foo } from "@types/common";
   |                            ^
22 |  const Expenses = ({
23 |    rent,
```

The error only affects enum imports/exports. I am able to import types or any other kind of data without problems.

Using `React v18.2`, `Vite v4.1`, `vite-tsconfig-paths v4.2` and `Typescript v4.9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED:** What I think it happens is that absolute importing enums as `@types/` was having conflicts with other `@types/` folders from dependency modules. Renaming the import to something else like `@_types` and reloading vite dev server just fixed the issue.